# Different line settings by Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I have to draw chart with different line settings (weight, pointSize, etc.). For example first line has to be 3px weight and 5px point size, but second - without points. I didn`t find option to configure chart in such way. There is a compound charts but it is a deprecated API. I also thought that I could call draw() method several times with different data and options, but it cleans previous drawing. So my question - how could I call draw multiple times without rewriting previous drawing or how I could configure chart to use custom formatting for different lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check the settings in the "series" option? Doc : https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: You have opened my eyes on it) Thank you very much. I don`t understand how i could`n see it..